# Relation between a Bezier curve and B-Spline curve

Tags: spline, bezier-curve

While the ideas behind Bezier curves are rather straight forward, I'm really struggling trying to understand B-Splines. I really researched quite a lot about it and still can't figure it out.

I would like to start with the objective: My aim is to chain a few **cubic** Bezier curves together in an efficient way. I basically have a set of points and I would like to fit a curve through all of them. There is already a nice and simple way to do so that is available online [here](https://medium.com/@ramshandilya/draw-smooth-curves-through-a-set-of-points-in-ios-34f6d73c8f9), that uses constraints on the meeting points (equality of points, derivative and 2nd derivative) to derive the control points.

But, I heard that B-Splines are also used for that purpose, and might be better for it.

The article [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120227050519/http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~455/bs.pdf) shows you can derive Bezier control points out of a B-Spline (in an easy manner). It also states that:

> "Whereas an open string of m Bezier curves of degree n involve nm + 1
>   distinct control points (shared control points counted only once),
>   that same string of Bezier curves can be expressed using only m + n
>   B-spline control points (assuming all neighboring curves are C n−1 )."

So,

1) is this the reason why I would like to use B-Splines? If not, what is the reason? Maybe I shouldn't use B-Splines at all?

2) a B-Spline is constructed using a set of control points. Which control points should I supply it, if I want it to pass through my data points?

Answer (score 3):

The reason to use B-spline curve instead of multiple Bezier curves are

1) B-spline curve has a more compact representation, i.e., it uses far fewer control points to represent the same shape.

2) B-spline curve representation has built-in continuity, which will not be destroyed when moving control points around. For example, a cubic B-spline curve with two Bezier segments have 5 control points. You are free to move these 5 control points and the $C^2$ continuity between the two segments is always maintained. If the same curve is represented by two Bezier curves with 7 control points ($P_0,P_1,...,P_6$ with $P_3$ the shared control point), moving any of $P_2$, $P_3$ or $P_4$ will destroy $C^1$ continuity unless you ensure that $P_3=(P_2+P_4)/2$.

If you would like to create a B-spline curve to pass through a given set of points, you can search against "B-spline interpolation" on internet.